# javascript ограничения?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть функция, в которой задается начальное значение отсчета и количество элементов ID ВКонтакте. А также переборка по 1000 штук и добавление в общую переменную.

```
 function getMembersUser(startVk, kolich) { 
   var membersGroupsStr;

  VK.api( "execute", { code: code }, function(data) {
  membersGroups = data.response;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   membersGroupsStr += '<br />'+i+':'+membersGroups[i].uid +' '+     membersGroups[i].first_name +' ' + membersGroups[i].last_name;
                    }
 $('.rez8').html(stStr);
}
```

Если начинаем перебирать с единицы `getMembersUser(1, 2100)`, то функция работает хорошо. Но если `getMembersUser(123456789, 2100)`

вот такое сообщение в консоли:

```
TypeError: membersGroups[i] is undefined    

membersGroupsStr += '<br />'+i+':'+membersGroups[i].uid +' '+ membersGroups[i].f...
```

Почему, есть ограничения на javascript у числа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто наступает момент, когда вы считали уже почти всех членов группы, и очередная пачка содержит не 1000, а меньше пользователей. Перебирайте не до 1000, а до длины массива:

```
for (var i = 0; i < membersGroups.length; i++) {
    ...
```

Что касается самого большого значения целого числа в JS, то это `2^53-1 = 9007199254740991`